# Show reputation decreases on top bar?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Early today, I logged in to SE, and the top bar (trophy cup icon) showed a rep change of +27. When I pulled it down to see the details, it showed +20 in each of two stacks (three actions - two different answers upvoted in one stack, one answer upvoted twice in a second stack). I went through all of my stacks, and found that the difference (-13) between +40 and +27 was accounted for by a removed question in a third stack.

Can the 'trophy cup' be fixed so that rep *decreases* are also reported?

Comment: I will concede that the proposed dupe is essentially the same question as I have; the fact that the question keeps recurring, however, suggests that the 'status-declined' on the feature request should perhaps be revisited. Alternatively, a well-documented summary showing both increases and decreases, generated at fixed intervals (daily? weekly?) and showing up in my InBox, might be an acceptable (to me) alternative.

Comment: There is an excellently-documented summary - on your profile/activity page in the "reputation" tab. :)

Comment: @Catija - for each stack, yes. But if I don't see which stack generated the deduction, I have to check all fifteen stacks that I'm a member of to find which one incurred the deduction - and I'm sure that there are folks that have joined even more stacks than I have, and hence have to go through a whole lot more to find those rep drops...

Comment: Negative reputation changes do show up in the dropdown... they just don't light it up. Figuring out which site it's on is pretty easy.